# How to retrieve only the records where stat changes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I want to get same output:

[image: I want to get the same output]

using the following sample data

```
create table x
(
     id int, 
     date datetime, 
     stat int
)

insert into x 
values (1, '2017-01-01', 100), (1, '2017-01-03', 100), (1, '2017-01-05', 100),
       (1, '2017-01-07', 150), (1, '2017-01-09', 150), (1, '2017-02-01', 150),
       (1, '2017-02-02', 100), (1, '2017-02-12', 100), (1, '2017-02-15', 100),
       (1, '2017-02-17', 150), (1, '2017-03-09', 150), (1, '2017-03-11', 150),
       (2, '2017-01-01', 100), (2, '2017-01-03', 100), (2, '2017-01-05', 100),
       (2, '2017-01-07', 150), (2, '2017-01-09', 150), (2, '2017-02-01', 150),
       (2, '2017-02-02', 100), (2, '2017-02-12', 100), (2, '2017-02-15', 100),
       (2, '2017-02-17', 150), (2, '2017-03-09', 150), (2, '2017-03-11', 150)
```

I tried to use something like this

```
with a as
(
    select 
        id, date,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by date order by id) as rowNum  
    from 
        x
), b as 
(
     select 
         id, date,
         ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id, stat order by date) as rowNum   
     from 
         x
)
select min(b.date)  
from a
join b on b.id = a.id
having max(a.date) > max(b.date)
```

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) scenario, where you only have islands. In this scenario what defines the start of an island is a change in the `stat` value within a `id`, while evaluating the dataset in `date` order.

The [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) window function is used below to compare values across rows, and see if you need to include it in the output.

```
select b.id
, b.stat
, b.date
from (
    select a.id
    , a.date
    , a.stat
    , case lag(a.stat,1,NULL) over (partition by a.id order by a.date asc) when a.stat then 0 else 1 end as include_flag
    from x as a
    ) as b
where b.include_flag = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to read more about the lag window function it helps a lot, I haven't used it before.